# Load content into tab at runtime on click using QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

So I have this code in a file `AnalysisDisplays.cpp`

```
void AnalysisDisplays::showAnalysisDisplays(QWidget *parent) {

    QMainWindow *mw = new QMainWindow(parent);

    mw->setWindowTitle("Equity Strategy Analysis");
    mw->setMinimumSize(750, 700);

    QTabWidget *tabw = new QTabWidget(mw);
    mw->setCentralWidget(tabw);

    for (QListWidgetItem *wi: listItems) {
        if (wi->checkState()) {
            std::string eqType = wi->text().toStdString();

            DisplayAnalysis *dw = new DisplayAnalysis();

            displays[currentDisplayId] = dw;

            //Add this tab to tab widget
            tabw->addTab(dw, eqType.c_str());

            dw->setDisplayId(currentDisplayId);
            currentDisplayId++;

            //dw->displayAnalysis(parseCSV->getDataForEquityType(eqType));
        }
    }

    //Show the main window
    mw->show();
}
```

The issue is that we may create many tabs which is super slow. The commented out line is what I want to run at runtime. The issue is I am currently making a QMainWindow and a QTabWidget and forgetting about it. I need to somehow hook an event to the QTabWidget so whenever a tab object (DisplayAnalysis) `dw` is clicked, it will call `dw->displayAnalysis(parseCSV->getDataForEquityType(eqType));` where eqType is the title of the tab. This will result in the tab content being populated.

There can be multiple windows open that call `showAnalysisDisplays` and they may contain different number of tabs. So each window has its own `QMainWindow` and `QTabWidget` but the `parseCSV` pointer remains the same.

So how can I hook an event to each tab like this, taking into account that there may be multiple windows open which need to load content at runtime when a tab is clicked?

Comment: Which part is the slow part? The `parseCSV->getDataForEquityType(eqType)` or the `dw->displayAnalysis(..)`? And do you really need to call it every time a tab is clicked, or just the first time it is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use signals/slots to connect `QTabWidget::currentChanged` to a custom slot then get the tab and tab title using `QTabWidget::tabText` for example:

```
void AnalysisDisplays::currentChangedSlot(int index) {
    std::string eqType = tabw->tabText(index).toStdString();
    DisplayAnalysis *dw = qobject_cast<DisplayAnalysis*>(tabw->widget(index)));

    dw->displayAnalysis(parseCSV->getDataForEquityType(eqType));
}
```

Comment: This worked fine (I actually ended up making my own tab class similar to what was done here: http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/qtQTabWidgetCurrentChanged.php#.VWMlFa6qpBd).

Also small error in your solution, you have a variable name in your case `qobject_cast<DisplayAnalysis *dw>` should be `qobject_cast<DisplayAnalysis *>`.